# How to extract the text inside a block in an HCL (HashiCorp Configuration Language) file using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a HashiCorp Configuration Language (HCL) file with this block.

```
database = {
    gdb_name            =   "XXXXX"
    sid_name            =   "XXXXX"
    createContainerDB   =   "True"
    numberOfPDBs        =   "1"
    pdb_name            =   "XXXXX"
    oracle_database_sid =   "XXXXX"
}
```

I need only the below text from it & assign the individual lines to different shell variables.

```
gdb_name
sid_name
createContainerDB
numberOfPDBs
pdb_name
oracle_database_sid
```

But the catch here is that the text within `database = {}` might change. So, I need to extract the text within `database = {}` dynamically & then assign it to variables.

How can I achieve this using Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job in `sed`, though it isn't especially pretty:

```
$ cat foo.txt
foo = {
    gdb_name            =   "XXXXX"
    sid_name            =   "XXXXX"
    createContainerDB   =   "True"
    numberOfPDBs        =   "1"
    pdb_name            =   "XXXXX"
    oracle_database_sid =   "XXXXX"
}

database = {
    gdb_name            =   "XXXXX"
    sid_name            =   "XXXXX"
    createContainerDB   =   "True"
    numberOfPDBs        =   "1"
    pdb_name            =   "XXXXX"
    oracle_database_sid =   "XXXXX"
}

bar = {
    sid_name            =   "XXXXX"
    createContainerDB   =   "True"
    numberOfPDBs        =   "1"
    pdb_name            =   "XXXXX"
}
$ sed -e '/^database = {/,/^}/!d;/ *\([^ ][^ ]*\) *= *.*"/!d; s//\1/' foo.txt
gdb_name
sid_name
createContainerDB
numberOfPDBs
pdb_name
oracle_database_sid
```

It deletes lines which are not between `database = {` and `}`. Then it checks to see if lines look like attributes. If they don't it deletes the line. If they do, it uses the regular expression (shared with the previous match) to substitute away everything apart from the attribute name.

The `sed` script looks like this when laid out nicely on separate lines:

```
/^database = {/,/^}/!d
/ *\([^ ][^ ]*\) *= *.*"/!d
s//\1/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, Jon. But it is not working on Mac. Looks like `sed` on Mac behaves differently.

```
root@shashank-mbp /U/s/Downloads# sed '/^database = {/,/^}/{/ *\([^ ]\+\) *= *.*"/!d; s//\1/;}' testHCL.txt
```

Where did you test it?

Comment: That was tested on GNU `sed` under Cygwin. Mac `sed` appears not be the GNU version. The most likely problem is that the sed `{` on a single line is a GNU extension. If you save the multiline version as `foo.sed` and try it  with `sed -f foo.sed` it might work...

Comment: Thanks once again, @Jon. But I can't seem to make it work on Mac :-( With the multi-line version as well, I am not getting any output.

Comment: Sorry, I'd used another GNU extension, the `\+` for 1 or more matching. Try this `sed -e '/^database = {/,/^}/{/ *\([^ ][^ ]*\) *= *.*"/!d; s//\1/}' foo.txt`

Comment: Once again, thank you so much for your efforts, @Jon.
Unfortunately, I still can't make it work. Getting this error now.

`sed: 1: "/^database = {/,/^}/{/  ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: I installed `gsed`, that is GNU `sed` for Mac. Even with this, I am failing. Not getting any output.

Below is what the command looks like.

`gsed -e '/^database = {/,/^}/{/ *\([^ ][^ ]*\) *= *.*"/!d; s//\1/}' terraform1.auto.tfvars`

Comment: Sorry for spamming. Your command works like a charm (using `gsed`) when I run it against a text file containing that block only. 

But when I run it against the actual HCL file, it is outputting other blocks as well in addition to the desired values.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't cover the non-matching case. Try the edit.

Comment: You're a champ @Jon :-) Thank you so much for your help. I greatly appreciate it! It is now working with the actual file as well. Thanks once again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100041/discussion-between-shashank-srivastava-and-jon).